# OCDM combined with ODI

Tags: oracle, etl, data-warehouse, oracle-data-integrator

**ODI** = ELT tool

**OCDM** = Data warehouse.

Is my understanding of the above correct ? More information/explanation is welcome.
Now my question is :

Is it possible to load into OCDM's pre-existing tables via ODI, when the source of ODI are in flatfiles/XML format ? If possible, how ?

Any links related to above are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible. OCDM is a solution using an Oracle 11g database to store the data, so ODI can definitely load it.

Actually OCDM comes out-of-the-box with adapters to load the data from NCC (Oracle Communications Network Charging and Control) and BRM (Oracle Communications Billing and Revenue Management), and these adapters are using ODI 11g – and optionally Golden Gate.
Each of these adapters is composed of some models and one ODI project holding interfaces and packages.

If you want to build you own integration process, it is just a standard loading from flat file to Oracle or XML to Oracle. Both of these are covered by the tutorials in the ODI 11g Series in the Oracle Learning Library : https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::NO:24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:5185,29

Comment: Thanks that really helps. Do you know any blogs/sites which focus on the mapping perspective i.e. for flat files column data to rdbms table columns ( communication domain related data ) and maybe transformations of the preliminary data as well ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, using  OCDM ad-ons to load the data (NCC, BRM)
NCC (Oracle Communications Network Charging and Control),
BRM (Oracle Communications Billing and Revenue Management),
and these adapters are using ODI 11g and ODI 12c and optionally Golden Gate also.

Answer (score 0):

ODI is mostly used to load historical data. For more real-time data , they use Oracle Golden Gate. However, OGG is used to load the data to staging, for data sync from staging to presentation they still use ODI>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible. You need normal standard interface writing techniques to implement this.